# Returning an array of structs from an unmanaged C++ function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unmanaged, managed

I am currently working on a group project where aside from the GUI which is done in C# all of the code is done in C++.

In C++ we are using a funtion that reads formatted text from a file and seperates it into an array of structs, an example of a struct is:

```
typedef struct example{
    string id;
    string name;
    string email;
    char status;
    string phone_number;
 }example;
```

And of an array:

```
example* example_arr=new example[10];
```

We then want to return that array from the C++ function and use it in C# (DLLImport) to display that info in a Form.

When I started thinking about the implementation of the C# part I realized that I'm pretty much clueless about how to approach it since I've never seen unmanaged memory being used in C#, so I started looking for possible solutions but most of the cases I found are about sending info the opposite direction(from C# to C++) or were rather unclear in their explanation. The only thing I got from them really is that the concept of marshalling might be of use, however, I couldn't really wrap my head around it.

I would honestly appreciate any help on the topic, I really want to make it happen even though I'm not experienced with handling unmanaged memory in C#.

**EDIT:**

I've tried implementing what Hans suggested but I've faced a problem.
The C# code runs, executes the C++ function which runs as well up until it gets to the return statement and just stops(doesn't break/throw just freezes like it's waiting for something to happen) which in return stops the C# code from continuing it's run.

This is the code(I simplified the struct for the sake of testing):

C++

```
///header file
typedef struct example
{
    int num;
    char str[5];
}example;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall test(a arr[],int len);

///Cpp file
int __stdcall test(example* arr,int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i].num = i;
        std::cout <<"arr["<<i<<"].num = "<< arr[i].num<<"\n";//for debugging purposes
        strcpy(arr[i][0].str, "test");
    }
    std::cout << "not yet\n";
    return -1;//*does not get executed*
}
```

C#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct example
    {
        public int num;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
        public string str;
    };

    [DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int test(out example[] arr,int len);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Form Loaded Event function
    {
        example[] arr = new example[10];
        int res = test(out arr,10);//*Code freezes here*

        Debug.WriteLine(res);
        _text.Text =arr[0].str;
    }
}
```

The output in the debug window is(should end with -1 if everything works):

```
arr[0].num = 0
arr[1].num = 1
arr[2].num = 2
arr[3].num = 3
arr[4].num = 4
arr[5].num = 5
arr[6].num = 6
arr[7].num = 7
arr[8].num = 8
arr[9].num = 9
not yet
```

I find it to be really weird, it might be some mechanic related to the [out] modifier but I've got not clue.

Comment: unmanaged memory actually has pretty good support in C#, however: it is usually much easier if you can handle the allocations (and thus the lifetime) from the C# side, essentially passing a pointer *in* to the C/C++ (the pointer could be from managed heap, unmanaged heap, or stack memory - it doesn't really matter). Is it possible to consider an API that allows the consumer to handle the allocation site?

Comment: You are heading for a crash into a memory management wall at a hundred miles an hour.  C# is not going to use the delete[] operator to release the allocation again.  It can't, guaranteed memory leak.  Always favor writing this code so you pass the C# array to the C++ code, along with its length, so the C++ code can simply fill the array elements.  A handle-based approach can work too, typically requires create(), getdata() and destroy() functions.  Where destroy() would use the delete[] operator.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly(I'm not a native speaker so I'm just making sure) you are suggesting to send the pointer created in C# to C++ and do all the assignments there so that I don't need to return anything and just access the the data when the function is done?

Comment: Yes.  [Out] required on the array argument so it knows it needs to copy the array back.  Don't skimp on the length argument since it is easy to corrupt the GC heap when you overflow the array bounds.

Comment: Hans, wouldn't I need to handle that in C++ as well? I assume a C# struct is different than a C++ one in some way

Comment: No, that is the job of the pinvoke marshaler to take care of.  You need a declaration for the struct both in the C++ and the C# code.  It needs to be an exact match, sizeof(example) in C++ must be equal to Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Example)) in C#.  Usually not a problem, won't hurt to check.

Comment: I will read on pinvoke marshalling and the Out keyword, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't pass serialized objects as XML or JSON in C# application instead of mapping structures in memory? It's less efficient but less fragile, too.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the lecturers responsible for the project demanded that we only use procedural programming (aside from the GUI which has to be OO) so breaking up the data read from the file into structures and manipulating the array is a big part of the C++ side of the project thus passing the data to C# any other way won't cut it. I could've just passed the entire data as a string and mess with it in C# or even the reading itself there but that can't be done for the same reason.